# Build Project with Maven

Tags: java, maven, jar

I have build my project which i created in Netbeans with Maven. 
I would like to open the built .jar - file but nothing happens.
I think that the problem is, that I have to specifiy the Main Class in the pom.xml file?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.myproject</groupId>
<artifactId>My_Project_name</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<build>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
      <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
        <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
        <version>10.10.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
        <artifactId>derbyclient</artifactId>
        <version>10.10.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20171018</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

This is also what my main class looks like.

```
package com.myproject.My_Project_name;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;


public class App {
     public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new OverviewScreen().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Please help!

Comment: Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now fixed the problem. I added the following code to my pom.xml file and now it works fine.

```
 <build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.2</version>
      <configuration>
        <archive>
          <manifest>
            <mainClass>Path.To.My.Mainfile</mainClass>
          </manifest>
        </archive>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure that your dependencies are up to date and that you have everything you need to be working on your project.  The best way to troubleshoot this problem is to start a new maven project and start adding each dependency one by one until you find which dependency is the problem.

Here is the example `pom.xml` that should be working...For today.

pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.myproject</groupId>
  <artifactId>My_Project_name</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>My_Project_name</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
        <artifactId>derbyclient</artifactId>
        <version>10.10.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20171018</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
        <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>




  </dependencies>
</project>
```

And so the main class will look like this:

```
package com.myproject.My_Project_name;
//import java.awt.Rectangle;
//import java.io.BufferedReader;
//import java.io.File;
//import java.io.FileInputStream;
//import java.io.FileOutputStream;
//import java.io.IOException;
//import java.io.InputStreamReader;
//import java.io.RandomAccessFile;


public class App {
     public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                //error in commented line below
                //new OverviewScreen().setVisible(true);
                System.out.println("hello");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

So it looks like you are encountering your issue when you are using the following code:

```
    new OverviewScreen().setVisible(true);
```

Then before exporting the project to a .jar, make sure you select the main  class of the application entry point.  In my case the wizard for exporting to .jar has it on the final page of the wizard and you must click next until you see it.  For this example, select App.java (not AppTest.java) as your main.

Specifying the main entry point for the program can also be done other ways.  If you want to ensure it's working, check to see if the program is manifested within command prompt:

```
C:\Users\Me\Documents>java -jar myProjectName.jar
```

Once the project has been exported as a .jar, attempt to execute it on the command prompt.

```
C:\Users\Me\Documents>java -cp myProjectName.jar com.myproject.My_Project_name.App
```

If your dependencies are working, and you exported the `.jar` with the main file selected properly you should result with the command line outputting:

```
hello
```

from running the `.jar`.  Also make sure you are entering the command when you are in the containing folder of the .jar file.

Comment: I have copied your dependencies but when I open the .jar nothing happens. In my opinion I have not defined the Java class which should be started by opening the .jar file.

Comment: ensure that the first line in your java class it has:
package com.myproject.My_Project_name;

Comment: This line is there.

Comment: @Zharin Does the class compile without anything in the main other than a simple System.out.println("hello world"); ?  For example, if you take all your code out of your main and are left with just that print line, does it compile properly?

Comment: It also compiles proberly with everything in there. So the build succeeds I can also run the complete programm correctly with Netbeans but when I build it and run it outside of Netbeans nothing happens.

Comment: Yes I think so.

Comment: No the code is executing proberly when I execute it in Netbeans but after the creation of a .jar file nothing happens anymore.

Comment: @Zharin When I export my project to a .jar I am getting no error, except for unused imports. I edited them out in the class.  I doubt this is what you're talking about.  Genuinely curious as to what error you're encountering.

Comment: @Zharin Are you trying to run the .jar file or something?

Comment: @Zharin I think the problem lies within the exporting wizard.  You must select the main class for your .jar file to execute when you are opening it.  I updated my answer to include a section on testing it with the command line.

Comment: Yes I am trying to run the jar file but nothing happens.
I also exporting my jar file with no error.